# Incompatible babel-loader and babel-core versions

Tags: npm, babeljs, package.json, babel-loader

I installed `babel-core`, `babel-loader`, and a few other packages via npm

```
npm install babel-loader babel-core ...
```

This resulted in the following definitions in my `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
  "babel-loader": "^8.0.0",
  ...
},
```

At the time of this question, the latest version of `babel-core` is indeed `6.26.3` and the latest version of `babel-loader` is `8.0.0` as per npmjs.com repository.

However when I run `npm install` again to verify everything, I get this message:

```
npm WARN babel-loader@8.0.0 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

Why would `babel-loader` depend on a version of `babel-core` that doesn't exist yet? And what's the recommended way to resolve this warning?

Thanks!

**EDIT** Looks like the `babel-loader` library was published only 4 days ago. Could this be a relatively recent problem caused by this being published?

[image]

Comment: To clarify, instead of `babel-core` you need to install `@babel/core`. There's not something wrong with the package, you've just installed the wrong core. Is there something we can do to improve documentation would this? The installation docs even include examples of both: https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-loader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it was a versioning issue as I suspected.

I went to the `babel-loader` [version history page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-loader) and found a version of `babel-loader` that was published around the same time as the latest `babel-core` version, so it was likely they would work well with each other.

In this case it was `7.1.4` from 6 months ago.

Everything worked great from there. It's incredibly disappointing that one of the key benefits of package managers is that they solve dependency issues but a project such as this has such a profoundly basic failure.

```
"dependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
  "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
  ...
},
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

`babel-loader@8.x` is the Webpack integration used for Babel 7.x. Babel 7.x has moved all packages from a `babel-` prefix to the `@babel` `npm` scope.

The error is correct, you have incorrectly installed `babel-core` instead of `@babel/core`.

If you wish to install Babel 6.x, you can do

```
npm install --save-dev babel-loader@7 babel-core
```

but if you're starting a new project, Babel 7 makes much more sense, so you would ideally do

```
npm install --save-dev babel-loader @babel/core
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error just 5 minutes ago, I fixed that with reinstalling babel-loader.

```
npm r babel-loader
npm i babel-loader@7
```